# Need help returning "1" "2" or "3" within switch statement

Tags: json, windows, powershell

I am creating a Switch statement through PowerShell. I am having trouble when running this code:

```
        ps c:\

                  switch((healthcheck)) {
'critical' {1}
'warning'  {2}
'healthy'  {3}
default    {999}  # not reading critical(1), warning(2), or healthy(3)}
```

---

output: 999

---

### It seems as if it cannot find the "critical, healthy, or warning" when I run (healthcheck) which looks like this:

ps c:\ healthcheck

---

output:

ResponseType Description    Message
------------ -----------    -------
Critical     Database Issue An error occurred while connecting to the database.........

---

****** The url I am using within the (healthcheck) function refreshes everytime giving critical, warning, or healthy. My GOAL is to translate critical, warning, or healthy to ==== 1, 2, or 3!

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your `healthcheck` function is returning what you (and your `if` statement) think/expect it to return?  If not, that's how it'd end up hitting the `else {"3"}`.  That URL doesn't work for me, by the way; if I run your `Invoke-RestMethod` command it throws an "Invoke-RestMethod : The remote name could not be resolved: 'toctest.cable.comcast.com'" error.

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod returns structured data that represents the HTTP response. It includes things that the status code the content length ect.  If you want the value you need to read the content of the response. 

You are getting 3 every time because the respose object cannot match any of your values.

Comment: Also, I'm not understanding "I can not create a variable due to it storing data."  The fact that your `if` block is comparing against two possible results should not (does not) mean you need to retrieve the remote resource twice.  If the first call to `healthcheck` returned `'Warning'` but on the second call (inside `elseif ( (healthcheck) -eq 'Warning')`) it returned something else, your code would miss that.

Comment: This has changed from a question about `if` to a question about `switch` but the problem remains your `healthcheck` function, the implementation of which has been removed from the question but we now see is throwing an error.  If your code is trying to make decisions based on the result of a successful query but the query _isn't_ succeeding, of course that's not going to work.  It's a bit like asking a true or false question and trying to interpret an answer of [`FileNotFound`](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_)...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP changed the question after various answers were given. In fact, the OP used one answer to rewrite the question for additional requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If the **THEN** is not executed, it means that the condition in the **IF** is not **TRUE**. 
So change to something like:

```
result = 0
if (value === "warning") {
   result = 1
} else {
   result = 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function `healthcheck` returns a string with possible values `critical`, `warning` or `healthy`, you can use the [Switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-6) statement, rather than a bunch of `if{..}`, `elseif{..}`, `else{..}` tests:

```
switch((healthcheck)) {
    'critical' {1}
    'warning'  {2}
    'healthy'  {3}
    default    {999}  # just in case the function returns something other than you expect..
}
```

If however your question is how to check the results of an `Invoke-RestMethod`, I suggest you edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Sigh.  At first I thought healthcheck was returning text...

```
function healthcheck {
  # [pscustomobject]@{ResponseType='Critical'}
  # [pscustomobject]@{ResponseType='Warning'}
  [pscustomobject]@{ResponseType='Nothing'}
}

switch ((healthcheck).responsetype) {
  'critical' {1}
  'warning'  {2}
  'healthy'  {3}
  default    {999}  
}
```